# Generate mesh from implicit function

Tags: python, python-3.x, mesh, implicit

I want to use Python (or Python 3) to generate a volume (3D) mesh from an implicit function:

```
def func(x,y,z):
    q = 0.25
    mu = q/(1.+q)
    return -(1-mu)*pow(x*x + y*y + z*z,-1./2.)  - mu*pow(pow(x-1,2) + y*y + z*z,-1./2.) - 0.5*(pow(x-mu,2) + y*y) + 1.9023266381531847
```

This function has a complicated isosurface, but I want to restrict the surface to be between x=-0.615 and x=1.4, and y = -0.6, y=0.6, there are no restrictions on the z-direction, but the interesting part is between z = +/- 1.

I have tried [pygalmesh](https://github.com/nschloe/pygalmesh), but I could not get their example to adapt to my function. It crashes my Python kernel without output. It is possible to get *pygalmesh* to do this? If not, what would be a better way?

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record, this doesn't crash without output for me:

```py
import numpy
import pygalmesh


class GrimReaper(pygalmesh.DomainBase):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def eval(self, x):
        q = 0.25
        mu = q / (1.0 + q)
        x, y, z = x
        return (
            -(1 - mu) / numpy.sqrt(x ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2)
            - mu / numpy.sqrt((x - 1) ** 2 + y ** 2 + z ** 2)
            - 0.5 * ((x - mu) ** 2 + y ** 2)
            + 1.9023266381531847
        )

    def get_bounding_sphere_squared_radius(self):
        return 2.0


d = GrimReaper()
mesh = pygalmesh.generate_mesh(d, cell_size=0.1)

mesh.write("out.xmf")
```

```
Inserting protection balls...
  refine_balls = true
  min_balls_radius = 0
  min_balls_weight = 0
insert_corners() done. Nb of points in triangulation: 0
insert_balls_on_edges() done. Nb of points in triangulation: 0
refine_balls() done. Nb of points in triangulation: 0

construct initial points (nb_points: 12)
s.py:17: RuntimeWarning: divide by zero encountered in double_scalars
  + 1.9023266381531847
12/12 initial point(s) found...
Start surface scan...Scanning triangulation for bad facets (sequential) - number of finite facets = 50...
Number of bad facets: 0
scanning edges (lazy)
scanning vertices (lazy)
end scan. [Bad facets:0]

Refining Surface...
Legend of the following line: (#vertices,#steps,#facets to refine,#tets to refine)
(12,0,0,0)
Total refining surface time: 1.90735e-05s

Start volume scan...Scanning triangulation for bad cells (sequential)... 20 cells scanned, done.
Number of bad cells: 1
end scan. [Bad tets:1]

Refining...
Legend of the following line: (#vertices,#steps,#facets to refine,#tets to refine)
(23,11,0,70) (18839.3 vertices/s)Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It works fine without the term `- 0.5 * ((x - mu) ** 2 + y ** 2)`.

The segfault points towards an issue in CGAL. Perhaps it's useful to file a bug there.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Strange that it seems to be that term that causes problems. I know that there is a weird point in the full function around x,y ~ (0.64,0), where the gradient of the surface vanishes, perhaps that is why it is difficult...
I will see if I can post something to a CGAL forum. Thanks again!